# Error 201 identifier INIT_REPORT must be declared

Tags: oracle, reportbuilder

i am new to sqlplus and i write a small program using report builder but its give me an error 201 at line 7, column 3, identifier 'INIT_REPORT' must be declared. Error 0 at line 7, column 3, statement ignored. Can someone advise me what did i miss? below is the program.

```
`function AfterPForm return boolean is
  pparamstring          varchar2(40) := Null;
  v_guest_language     varchar2(4)  := Null;
  v_dtl_curr_yn        varchar2(2)  :='N';
  v_sum_curr_yn        varchar2(2)  := 'N';
begin
  init_report(:p_report_name,:p_user,:p_password,:p_resort,:p_business_date);
  commit;
  :p_user := replace(:p_user,','||nvl(:p_language_code,'E'));
  fin_trx_i.load_app_params(:p_resort);

   SELECT pms_p.currency,
         nvl(fin_trx_i.get_parameter('SHOW_AR_SETTLEMENT'),'N'),nvl(fin_trx_i.get_parameter('AR_SETTLE_CODE'),'@'),
         nvl(multi_currency.get_exchange_rate(pms_p.currency,null,'EUR','P',pms_p.business_date,pms_p.resort),0),
         PMS_P.GET_PARAMETER('CURRENCY_FORMAT'),NVL(PMS_P.GET_PARAMETER('EXT_DEPOSIT_HANDLING'),'0')
     INTO :P_CURRENCY,:p_show_ar_settlement,:p_settle_code,:p_euro_exch_rate,:P_curr_format,:p_deposit_mode
    FROM DUAL;

  fin_trx_i.set_folio_type(:p_folio_type);
  fin_trx_i.set_folio_type2(:p_folio_type2);
  fin_trx_i.set_bill_no(:p_bill_no);
  fin_trx_i.set_queue_name(:p_queue_name);
  fin_trx_i.set_bill_generation_date(:p_bill_generation_date);

  :associated_bill_no := :p_associated_bill_no;
  :queue_name := :p_queue_name;
--  if :rname_id is null then Preview_Values; end if;
  if :rname_id is not null then
        :where_cl_detail := ' Where  FOLIO_DETAIL_VIEW_V2.FOLIO_STYLE = fin_trx_i.get_folio_style    and
                       FOLIO_DETAIL_view_v2.FOLIO_VIEW_DETAIL >=:FOLIONR1 and
                       FOLIO_DETAIL_view_v2.FOLIO_VIEW_DETAIL <=:FOLIONR2 and
                       folio_detail_view_v2.phone_details = :PHONE_EN_DIS and ';
  else
    :where_cl_detail := ' Where  FOLIO_DETAIL_VIEW_V2.FOLIO_STYLE = fin_trx_i.get_folio_style    and ';
  end if;

  If :foliono is Not Null Then
    :where_cl_header := ' where FOLIO_HEADER_View.folio_style = fin_trx_i.get_folio_style ';
    :where_cl_detail := :where_cl_detail || ' folio_detail_view_v2.FOLIO_NO_DETAIL = :foliono ';
    :where_cl_footer := ' where folio_footer_v2.folio_style =  fin_trx_i.get_folio_style  and folio_footer_V2.folio_no_footer = :foliono ';
  else
    :where_cl_header := ' where FOLIO_HEADER_View.folio_style = fin_trx_i.get_folio_style and FOLIO_HEADER_View.RESV_NAME_ID_HEADER = :RNAME_ID ';
    :where_cl_detail := :where_cl_detail || ' folio_detail_view_v2.RESV_NAME_ID_DETAIL = :RNAME_ID ';
    :where_cl_footer := 'where folio_footer_v2.folio_style = fin_trx_i.get_folio_style and folio_footer_V2.resv_name_id_footer = :RName_ID ';
  end if;

  if :p_invoice_no is not null then
    :where_cl_header := :where_cl_header||' and FOLIO_HEADER_View.invoice_NO = :p_invoice_no ';
  end if;
  if not (:p_bill_no = -1 or :p_bill_no is null) then
    :where_cl_header := :where_cl_header||' and FOLIO_HEADER_View.bill_Number_header = :p_bill_no ';
  end if;
  :where_cl_header := :where_cl_header || ' and rownum < 2 ';

  :where_cl_merchant := :where_cl_merchant ||
     '  and ( ( :p_bill_no is null and bill_number_merchant is null ) or ' ||
     '        ( nvl( bill_number_merchant, 0 ) = decode( :p_bill_no, -1, nvl( bill_number_merchant, 0 ), :p_bill_no ) ) ) ';


  if ( :p_fromdate is not null and :p_todate is not null ) then
    :where_cl_detail := :where_cl_detail ||' and folio_detail_view_v2.direct_trx_date between :p_fromdate and :p_todate';
  end if;

  :where_cl_detail := :where_cl_detail ||' '||:p_orderby;

  if ( nvl(:Pdetail_currency,:p_currency)!=:p_currency) then
       fin_trx_i.set_detail_currency(:pdetail_currency);
       v_dtl_curr_yn := 'Y';
  end if;
  if (nvl(:Psummary_currency,:p_currency)!=:p_currency) then
       v_sum_curr_yn := 'Y';
       fin_trx_i.set_summary_currency(:psummary_currency);
  end if;

  if ( :foliono != 0 ) then
     begin
--srw.messagE(1,'resv name id '||:rname_id||'FOLIO TYPE '||:P_FOLIO_TYPE2||' invoice no '||:p_invoice_no||' p_bill_no = '||:p_bill_no||' folio no= '||:foliono||' folios '||:folios||'folio view '||:folionr1||' - '||:folionr2||' trxno '||:p_inv_trx_no||' bill_no = '||:p_bill_no);

    fin_trx_i.gstfolio_param(:p_udfc1,:p_udfc2,:p_udfc3,:p_udfc4,:p_udfc5,
                                                        :p_udfn1,:p_udfn2,:p_udfn3,:p_udfn4,:p_udfn5,
                                                        :p_udfd1,:p_udfd2,:p_udfd3,:p_udfd4,:p_udfd5);

     folio_detail_cursor.set_folio_parameters(in_resv_name_id  => :RNAME_ID,
                                     in_invoice_no    => :p_invoice_no,
                                     in_Lang_yn       =>   'Y',
                                     in_dtl_curr_yn   => v_dtl_curr_yn,
                                     in_sum_curr_yn   => v_sum_curr_yn ,
                                     in_lang_code     => :p_language_code,
                                     in_dtl_curr      => :pdetail_currency,
                                     in_sum_curr      => :psummary_currency ,
                                     in_folio_no      => :foliono,
                                     in_folio_type    => :p_folio_type2,
                                     in_bill_no       => :p_bill_no,
                                     in_folio_view1   => :folionr1,
                                     in_folio_view2   => :folionr2,
                                     in_folio_style   => :folios,
                                     in_phone_details => :phone_en_dis,
                                     in_cashier_id    => :cashid,
                                     in_trx_no        => :p_inv_trx_no,
                                     in_from_date     =>:p_fromdate,
                                     in_to_date       =>:p_todate,
                                     in_user_name     =>:p_user,
                                     in_password      =>:p_password,
                                     in_resort        =>:p_resort,
                                     in_populate_deposit_info => nvl(:p_populate_deposit_info,'N'));
--srw.message(1,'folio style '||fin_trx_i.get_folio_style);
--commit;
    exception
      when others then
        srw.message( 1, 'Error:(' || sqlerrm || ')' );
        return(true);
    end;
  end if;

  /*****************************
  commit;
  srw.message( 1, 'header (' || :where_cl_header || ')' );
  srw.message( 1, 'detail (' || :where_cl_detail || ')' );
  srw.message( 1, 'footer (' || :where_cl_footer || ')' );
  srw.message( 1, 'merc (' || :where_cl_merchant || ')' );
  srw.message( 1, 'end of backend call..' );
  **********************/

  return (TRUE);
exception
  when others then
    srw.message(0,sqlerrm);
    return(true);
end;`
```

what did i miss regarding on this issue

Comment: I am not sure if this is something specific to report builder but you appear to be using bind variables (prefixed with `:`) throughout your function. If this is just being evaluated as PL/SQL (i.e. there is not a preprocessor for report builder) then using bind variables is wrong and you should be using PL/SQL variables and defining them before the `BEGIN` statement.

Comment: @MT0, that's OK - these are reports' parameters and they are referenced with a colon character in front of their names.

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

> ```
> 'INIT_REPORT' must be declared. Error 0 at line 7, column 3, statement ignored.
> ```

On line 7 you have the code:

```sql
  init_report(:p_report_name,:p_user,:p_password,:p_resort,:p_business_date);
```

Exactly as the error message states, the database is saying that there is no procedure declared with the identifier `init_report`.

You need to create an `init_report` procedure.

Comment: its turn out, i forgot to attach rep_gen.pll library in Report Builder. Its solved the problem after i attached rep_gen.pll library. Thank you all for your assistance.